# How to convert Date.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_yy_HH_mm_ss_ms") in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, formatting, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a C# statement:

```
Date.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_yy_HH_mm_ss_ms")
```

Now, I need to use the same in SQL Server 2008 R2. I know I can use `GETDATE` for current date. But unable to get this format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
select cast(year(getdate()) as char(4))+'_'+
       case when month(getdate())<10 then '0'+cast(month(getdate()) as char(1)) else cast(month(getdate()) as char(2)) end+'_'+
       right(cast(datepart(yy,getdate()) as char(4)),2)+'_'+
       replace(replace(right(convert(varchar(22),getdate(),121),11),':','_'),'.','_')
```

#### [SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6570)

Comment: This is still not the exact pattern

Comment: @user960567: is space  the problem ? please check now

Comment: @JoeGJoseph, please see the format deeply yyyy_MM_yy_HH_mm_ss_ms

Comment: @user960567: Please check now

Comment: @JoeGJoseph Now it works. But below solution is more clean I think. Thanks anyway

Comment: Just a hint. Be careful what you use as test data when formatting dates. You may find that tests using getdate don't work for the first nine months of the year (best not use getdate after September) or the first nine days of the year ! The accepted solution is a case-in-point. Also, did you really mean to have "yy" (year) twice in your format ?

Comment: Close... but no cigar. Try replacing "getdate()" with "01-Feb-2012" and you'll see my point. Getting string manipulation like this working in T-SQL is like a juggling dog. You may well get it to work, but it ain't gonna be pretty. :o)

Comment: @BlackLight: I think , its working ...  please check this... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6571

Comment: Nearly right... Try "right(100 + month(@now),2)" instead of your case, and "right(convert(varchar(22),@now,121),11)" for the time.

Answer (score 2):

Try out function here

Read more about this : [Formatted date in SQL Server 2008](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3820771/Formatted-date-in-SQL-Server-2008.htm)

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[format_date]    Script Date: 05/12/2009 23:19:35 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[format_date]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[format_date]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[format_date]    Script Date: 05/12/2009 23:19:18 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
go
CREATE function [dbo].[format_date] (@inputdate datetime ,@format varchar(500))
returns varchar(500)
as
begin
declare @year varchar(4)                --YYYY
declare @shortyear varchar(4)           --Yr
declare @quarter varchar(4)             --QQ
declare @month varchar(2)               --MM
declare @week varchar(2)                --WW
declare @day varchar(2)                 --DD
declare @24hours varchar(2)             --24HH
declare @12hours varchar(2)             --HH
declare @minutes varchar(2)             --MI
declare @seconds varchar(2)             --SS
declare @milliseconds varchar(3)        --MS
declare @microseconds varchar(6)        --MCS
declare @nanoseconds varchar(9)         --NS
declare @dayname varchar(15)            --DAY
declare @monthname varchar(15)          --MONTH
declare @shortmonthname varchar(15)     --MON
declare @AMPM    varchar(15)            --AMPM
declare @TZ  varchar(15)                --TZ
declare @UNIXPOSIX   varchar(15)        --UNIXPOSIX
                                        --UCASE
                                        --LCASE

declare @formatteddate varchar(500)     

--Assign current date and time to 
if (@inputdate is NULL or @inputdate ='')
begin
set @inputdate = getdate()
end

if (@format is NULL or @format ='')
begin
set @format ='YYYY-MM-DD 12HH:MI:SS AMPM'
end

--set all values

set @year         = convert(varchar(4),year(@inputdate))
set @shortyear    = right(@year,2)
set @quarter      = convert(varchar(1),datepart(QQ,(@inputdate)))
set @month        = right('0'+convert(varchar(2),month(@inputdate)),2)
set @week         = right('0'+convert(varchar(2),datepart(ww,(@inputdate))),2)
set @day          = right('0'+convert(varchar(2),day(@inputdate)),2)
set @24hours      = right('0'+convert(varchar(2),datepart(hh,@inputdate)),2)
set @TZ           = convert(varchar(10),datename(TZ,convert(varchar(20),@inputdate)))
set @UNIXPOSIX    = convert(varchar(15),datediff(ss,convert(datetime,'01/01/1970 00:00:000'),@inputdate))

if datepart(hh,@inputdate) >12
begin
set @12hours      = right('0'+convert(varchar(2),datepart(hh,@inputdate)) -12,2)
end
else
begin
set @12hours      = right('0'+convert(varchar(2),datepart(hh,@inputdate)) ,2)
end

if datepart(hh,@inputdate) >11 
begin
set @AMPM ='PM'
end
else
begin
set @AMPM ='AM'
end

set @minutes      = right('0'+convert(varchar(2),datepart(n,@inputdate)),2)
set @seconds      = right('0'+convert(varchar(2),datepart(ss,@inputdate)),2)
set @milliseconds = convert(varchar(3),datepart(ms,@inputdate))
set @microseconds = convert(varchar(6),datepart(mcs,@inputdate))
set @nanoseconds  = convert(varchar(9),datepart(ns,@inputdate))
set @dayname      = datename(weekday,@inputdate)
set @monthname    = datename(mm,@inputdate)
set @shortmonthname= left(datename(mm,@inputdate),3)
set @formatteddate = @format
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'MONTH',@monthname)
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'MON',@shortmonthname)
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'AMPM',@AMPM)

set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'YYYY',@year)
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'Yr',@shortyear)
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'QQ',@quarter)
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'WW',@week)
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'MM',@month)
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'DD',@Day)
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'24HH',@24hours)
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'12HH',@12hours)
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'Mi',@minutes)
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'SS',@seconds)
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'MS',@milliseconds)
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'MCS',@microseconds)
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'NS',@nanoseconds)
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'DAY',@dayname)
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'TZ',@TZ)
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'UNIXPOSIX',@UNIXPOSIX)

if charindex('ucase',@formatteddate)<>0
begin
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'ucase','')
set @formatteddate=upper(@formatteddate)
end

if charindex('lcase',@formatteddate)<>0
begin
set @formatteddate=replace(@formatteddate,'lcase','')
set @formatteddate=lower(@formatteddate)
end


return @formatteddate
end


GO
```

Comment: @user960567 - you should accept answer that satisfy you requirement properly....any ways no issues if that anwser work for you properly...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), SYSDATETIME(), 120)
```

for format of  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS(24h)

refer here for different formats

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx

Comment: Nice link, but does this answer the question which contains `_`s and is not ISO 8601 (for whatever reason)? That is, will this work even if the separators are different?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    select cast(DATEPART(yy,getdate()) as CHAR(4))+'_'+
           cast(DATEPART(mm,getdate()) as CHAR(2))+'_'+
           right(cast(DATEPART(yy,getdate()) as CHAR(4)),2)+'_'+
           cast(DATEPART(HH,getdate()) as CHAR(2))+'_'+
           cast(DATEPART(mi,getdate()) as CHAR(2))+'_'+
           cast(DATEPART(ss,getdate()) as CHAR(2))+'_'+
           cast(DATEPART(MILLISECOND ,getdate()) as CHAR(5))
```